# Integrating a particular form on a manifold

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

Consider the set $S = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x^2+y^2+z^2=1, z\geq 0\}$.

We need to compute $$\int_S  \omega $$ 
on $S$ where $\omega$ is given as follows:

$\omega = dydz/x$ when $x \neq 0$,  $\omega = dzdx/y$ when $y \neq 0$,  $\omega = dxdy/z$ when $z \neq 0$.

My guess is to cover $S$ with 3 coordinate charts such that they match the conditions of domain of definition of $\omega$.

Can someone show the explicit computation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're only integrating over the upper hemisphere, you can work just with the formula $\omega = \dfrac{dx\wedge dy}z$. (Officially, you are missing a set of measure $0$ when you integrate over the open hemisphere, rather than the closed hemisphere. However, the fact that $\omega$ is given by the other formulas when $z=0$ shows you that in fact $\omega$ is smooth everywhere and there is no problem. By the way, you should check why 
$$\frac{dx\wedge dy}z = \frac{dy\wedge dz}x = \frac{dz\wedge dx}y \quad\text{when } x,y,z\ne 0.)$$
At any rate, this gives an improper integral, but it converges just fine. Switching to polar coordinates, we get
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 \frac r{\sqrt{1-r^2}}dr\wedge d\theta.$$
You can finish from here.

Comment: The equality you wrote for those 3 expressions works by considering the function $x^2+y^2+z^2$ and 1 as its regular value. So we take "d" and successively wedge with dx,dy,dz.

Comment: Great :) Glad you understand!